# What's a word for a statement that's not quite factual?

Tags: phrases, nouns

What's a word for a statement that's not quite factual? Not quite a myth, but not quite a fact either. Like "truthy" but not an adjective? For example, "scientists are still looking for the missing link." It's true that scientists are still researching evolution, but not in the sense that there is a "missing link" since there will always be a fossil between any two fossils.

Comment: *Theory*? - a proposed explanation whose status is still conjectural and subject to experimentation, in contrast to well-established propositions that are regarded as reporting matters of actual fact. [dictionary.reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/theory)

Comment: There is, of course, "apocryphal".  And "anecdotal".

Comment: And in some cases "metaphorical" or "figurative" may fit.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking of [*half-truth* - "a statement that is only partly true, especially one intended to deceive, evade blame, or the like."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/half-truth?s=t)